# iphone NSManagedObject - The proper way of deallocing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a sub-class of NSManagedObject, most of the properties are dynamic (created by the managed object), but i have a couple of helper properties which are being created as @synthesize.

What is the correct way of releasing these objects??

```
- (void)didTurnIntoFault
{
     [self.randomVar release];
     [super didTurnIntoFault];
}
```

or

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     [self.randomVar release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override `didTurnIntoFault` and release them there. Managed objects aren't necessarily deallocated when they're faulted.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html):

> You are discouraged from overriding `dealloc` or `finalize` because `didTurnIntoFault` is usually a better time to clear values—a managed object may not be reclaimed for some time after it has been turned into a fault. Core Data does not guarantee that either `dealloc` or `finalize` will be called in all scenarios (such as when the application quits); you should therefore not in these methods include required side effects (like saving or changes to the file system, user preferences, and so on).

Comment: Fyi to people like me who are confused by the name of the override-- willTurnIntoFault does not in any way indicate an error or "fault", it's just the CoreData term for taking an object out of circulation.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a closer look at The Core Data Programming Guide. These two passages are of particular relevance

> If you define custom instance
>   variables, you should clean up these
>   variables in didTurnIntoFault rather
>   than dealloc or finalize.

and

> You should typically not override
>   dealloc or finalize to clear transient
>   properties and other variables.
>   Instead, you should override
>   didTurnIntoFault.

Answer (score 4):

[This should be a comment really because I'm pointing out a different problem to the question, but I want the code formatting functionality].

Never do this:

```
[self.randomVar release];
```

That releases the object pointed to by the property backing ivar but does not make the pointer itself nil.  This means you now potentially have a dangling pointer if the release results in the object being dealloced.  Either do this:

```
self.randomVar = nil;
```

or this

```
[randomVar release];  // assumes the property is backed by an ivar of the same name.
randomVar = nil;      // can be omitted if you are in dealloc
```

The first form is preferred anywhere except in dealloc.